# Подключение MySQL в Qt5

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu, qt, qt5

Возникла проблема с подключением MySQL в Qt5:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setDatabaseName("db");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setPassword("123456");
db.open();
```

В консоли выводит:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Как советуют в некоторых мануалах, обнаруженных на просторах Интернета, обратился к команде:

```
$> ldd libqsqlmysql.so

    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb775d000)
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb7705000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb76d2000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0xb76b7000)
    libssl.so.10 => not found
    libcrypto.so.10 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0xb766d000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xb712d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7110000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb701b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6fce000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6fb1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6df5000)
    libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0xb6bd5000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0xb6a54000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6a4f000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb6927000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb691d000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb775e000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0xb52b0000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb523e000)
```

Видно, что не все зависимости удовлетворены. MySQL-клиент у меня установлен версии 18. Пересобрал плагин, как указано в [справке Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql-for-mysql-4-and-higher). Всё прошло без ошибок, файл плагина новой версии был создан успешно. Проверяю его также через `ldd`:

```
$> ldd libqsqlmysql.so

    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb773c000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0xb7371000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/alexis/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0xb7329000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/alexis/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xb6ddf000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb6cea000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb6b2f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb6b14000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb6b0f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6af1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb6aa4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6a87000)
    libicui18n.so.54 => /home/alexis/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libicui18n.so.54 (0xb680e000)
    libicuuc.so.54 => /home/alexis/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libicuuc.so.54 (0xb6666000)
    libicudata.so.54 => /home/alexis/Qt/5.5/gcc/lib/libicudata.so.54 (0xb4e3a000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xb4e37000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb4e2e000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb4d06000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb773d000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xb4c93000)
```

Как хорошо видно, теперь все зависимости удовлетворены и, по идее, плагин должен без проблем подключаться и работать. И он таки подключается:

```
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

... но не работает:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
```

Пути подгрузки плагинов и библиотек проверял.

Что ещё возможно придумать в сложившейся ситуации для решения проблемы?

Примечание: [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406044/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-mysql-%D0%B2-qt-5-3), однако его автор не опубликовал ответ.

**Обновление**

Что называется, проблема из серии "сам дурак". Когда я пересобрал плагин под новую версию клиента, я решил старый не удалять, а просто переименовал его, рассудив, что раз уж имя файла поменялось, то и конфликта не возникнет. Однако по неведомой причине именно старый плагин подключался в программу вместо нового. Когда же я удалил старый файл из папки, новый плагин успешно подключился. Таким образом, сборка MySQL-плагина под новую версию (18) клиента вполне работоспособна.

Comment: т.е., пакет `libqt5sql5-mysql` у вас нерабочий и вы его пересобирали? может быть, не все зависимости были установлены? или, как это приходится (и рекомендуется) делать в *ubuntu*, репозитории какие-нибудь подключены помимо «официпальных»?

Comment: Требуется именно 16 версия, а не 18.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , нет, не пересобирал и не ставил даже этот пакет. У меня Qt 5.5 последней версии, а в репозитории убунты только 5.4. Думаете, причина в этом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая историю появления данного вопроса и свой опыт, предположу, что вы столкнулись с той же проблемой что и я. Раньше QT требовал именно версию 16, а не 18, которую вы пытаетесь использовать. Проверить это можно таки способом:

```
QPluginLoader loader;
loader.setFileName("/opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so");
loader.load();
qDebug() << loader.errorString();
```

И получите ошибку такого плана:

> Cannot load library
>   /opt/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so:
>   (libmysqlclient_r.so.16: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный
>   файл: Нет такого файла или каталога)"

Решение собрать версию 16 например так:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/75954717/libmysqlclient16_5.1.58-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg --extract ./libmysqlclient16_5.1.58-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./123
```

Полученный файл скопировать в папку где лежит 18 версия.

Comment: то есть, если я даже собираю без проблем плагин под 18 версию, я всё равно не могу его использовать? С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @alexis031182 С каким-то не совсем понятным решением разработчиков QT. Если честно я не вникал, требует значит требует. Некоторые решали вопрос в лоб создавая ссылку на 18 версию с нужным именем в нужной папке. Для начала можете просто попробовать создать ссылку с именем 16. Иногда и такой вариант может сработать. Обратил внимание что у вас 32 битная система, а мой пример 64 бита, но думаю вы сами легко всё сделаете для 32 битной системы.

Comment: ссылку пробовал создать, к сожалению не помогло. Если не найду способа, как обойтись без даунгрейда клиента, то попробую воспользоваться способом, что Вы опубликовали. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexis031182 Без вопросов, ваше право. Если найдете не забудьте поделится с нами вашим решением.

Comment: На убунту можно просто `dpkg -i ./libmysqlclient16_5.1.58-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`