# Qt : QMYSQL driver not loaded ( Linux )

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu, qt

При сборке проекта не возникает ошибок, но в "Выводе приложения"

Вот такие строки:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Он говорит что `QMYSQL` не установлен, а потом сам же его предлагает.

Подключение к базе соответственно не проходит. Подскажите что делать.

- Qt 5.4
- Ubuntu 15.04

// .pro

```
QT       += core gui
QT += network
QT += sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DBMS_Students
TEMPLATE = app

QTPLUGIN += QSQLMYSQL
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        dbms.cpp \
    students.cpp

HEADERS  += dbms.h

FORMS    += dbms.ui
```

//

```
/opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers
```

- libqsqlite.so
- libqsqlmysql.so
- libqsqlpsql.so

Comment: Вам нужно выполнить сборку собственного [плагина](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452480/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-mysql-%D0%B2-qt5).

Comment: @alexis031182 , нет это не мой случай, я проверил

Answer (score 2):

То, о чем уже говорилось в другом вопросе:

> Cannot load library
>   /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so:
>   (libmysqlclient_r.so.16: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный
>   файл: Нет такого файла или каталога)"

Установим libmysqlclient нужной версии:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/75954717/libmysqlclient16_5.1.58-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./libmysqlclient16_5.1.58-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Далее смотрим:

```
$ ldd /opt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff727fe000)
        libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0806de9000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f0806baf000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f0806995000)
        libssl.so.10 => not found
        libcrypto.so.10 => not found
```

Нет нужных dll. 
Удостоверимся, что libssl установлен:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

Создадим ссылки:

```
cd  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

Вуаля заработало.

Это наверно лишнее:

```
QTPLUGIN += QSQLMYSQL
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместе с MySQL поставляется библиотека клиента, путь к которой нужно добавить в переменную окружения Path (или скопировать в папку, уже добавленную в Path). Где в Linux хранится данная библиотека, к сожалению не знаю. Плагины собирать вручную не надо, в этой версии qt они уже собраны.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло установить библиотеку с драйвером mysql for qt5

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня проблема решилась установкой XAMPP, ничего не прописывал, видимо система сама прописала путь в переменную среды. Но на остальных система ( я ставил на все ( Windows, OS X ) ) проблема так и не решилась.